Create Vertical Scrolling Text in UserForm
Trying to create a userform in VBA excel where in the text can be scrolled vertically to show what I add in specific cells of excel. I am using version 2016 of excel.
Have taken VBA code from google which is given below:
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("b4").Value
    
    Me.Label2.Caption = Sheet1.Range("E9").Value & _
    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Sheet1.Range("E10").Value & _
    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Sheet1.Range("E11").Value & _
    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Sheet1.Range("E12").Value & _
    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Sheet1.Range("E13").Value
    
    Me.Label2.Top = Me.Height
End Sub

This part of code works well when I comment Me.Label2.Top = Me.Height this part of the code.
The second part of the code is for Vertical Scroll where in the scrolling happens however the loop where in the scrolling has to be repeated is not working. Code given below:
Sub verti_scroll()
    Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)

    Do
        i = UserForm1.Height - 42
        Do
            i = i - 1
            DoEvents
            For a = i To 5000000
                a = a + 1
            Next
            UserForm1.Label2.Top = i
            If i = 100 Then GoTo Nextz
        Loop
Nextz:
        x = x + 1
        If x = 2 Then GoTo nextx
    Loop
nextx:
End Sub

Trying to create a userform in VBA excel where in the text can be scrolled vertically to show what I add in specific cells of excel. I am using version 2016 of excel.
The second part of the code is for Vertical Scroll where in the scrolling happens however the loop where in the scrolling has to be repeated which is not working or other option is to stop the vertical scroll on the user form.
If anyone can help with the code or any other way would be really appreciable.

Thanks Siddharth for your help. However the issue here is to display text as scrolling up. Sharing the link with you to so that you can help with the actual issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKiiYPCtNlA

I have demonstrated both horizontal and vertical scroll. I have also commented the code. If you still have any questions, then simply please ask.
HORIZONTAL SCROLL (Like a ticker)
Paste this in the userform code module.
Option Explicit

Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    '~~> Sample scrolling text. Chnage as applicable
    Me.Label1.Caption = "Your scrolling text goes here. "
    ScrollText
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollText()
    Dim text As String
    
    text = Me.Label1.Caption
    
    '~~> Infinite loop to scroll the text
    Do
        '~~> This is required if user tries to close the userform
        If ExitLoop = True Then Exit Do
        
        '~~> Move the first character to the end
        text = Mid(text, 2) & Left(text, 1)
        
        Me.Label1.Caption = text
        
        Wait 0.1
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ExitLoop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Double)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

In action

VERTICAL SCROLL (Like movie credits)
Vertical scrolling is slightly different than horizontal scrolling.
Arrange your form accordingly.

Add a Frame control to the UserForm. This will act as the container for the scrolling text.
Add a Label control inside the Frame. Set its properties as needed (font size, font color, etc.). Make sure the label is large enough to display the text.

Something like this.

Userform Code Module
Option Explicit

Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    '~~> Start the scrolling loop
    ScrollText
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ExitLoop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Double)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollText()
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Set step size (adjust as needed)
    i = 1
    
    '~~> Set initial position
    Me.Label1.Top = 0
    
    '~~> Infinite loop to scroll the text
    Do
        '~~> This is required if user tries to close the userform
        If ExitLoop = True Then Exit Do
        
        '~~> Move label upward
        Me.Label1.Top = Me.Label1.Top - i
        
        Wait 0.1
        
        '~~> Reset label position if it goes out of the frame
        If Me.Label1.Top + Me.Label1.Height < 0 Then Me.Label1.Top = Me.Frame1.Height
    Loop
End Sub

In Action

Cross Posted at
mrexcel.com
excelforum.com

Thanks so much Siddhart for helping me out here. Really appreciate it. The code you have provided works absolutely great, as the scrolling is happening as desired. There are two things where I require your further help.

Where do I add all the text? In the label itself? and further the text I want to add has to be in different excel rows such as Heading1 - ABCD, Heading2-EFGH so on and so forth and this text would be Dynamic and has to be changed after a while
Also, how do I increase or decrease the speed of movement of the text
Hope not bothering to much. Thanks


1. You can add the text in the UserForm_Initialize() as you have done in the question. 2. To increase the speed change the value i = 1. To decrease, use a timer

Thanks so much Siddharth . Really appreciate the help you have provided. The code is working absolutely perfectly. Pasted the code below your code its working perfectly. Really appreciate your help. Would contact you in case of any help needed. Really appreciate it.
